# Connecting Linux Mint via Ethernet

Tags: networking, linux-mint

Absolute 'nix newbie here.
I have downloaded Linux Mint onto a USB stick in order to try it out and play around with it. It's loaded on and old Dell XP laptop.
It loads OK, but what I am having trouble with is attempting to connect it with the outside world.
I initially tried via wifi, to no avail, so connected it directly to my router via ethernet cable.
Now either I am being completely thick (entirely possible) or I am missing something. I am an ex (now well retired) mainframe programmer, but extensive user of Win software, but no very little about networking. The advantage that I can see of Windows is that connecting to or setting up networks seems to work without much problem, as opposed to my efforts with Mint.
I don't know. maybe I can't do it from a USB stick.
Whenever I go into Network Settings it appears that I have to set everything up from scratch as it asks for IPv4 address, amongst other esoteric requests.
I know what my router name is, I know what my network name is used from my other Win laptop and use it without much trouble. I am tearing my hair out over this one.
Anyone out there who can give me some clues as to how to go about it?
Incidentally, I have followed some instructions from elsewhere, but the problem with that is their instructions didn't match up with what I was seeing.
Heeelp!!!
Norris

Comment: have you tried to issue the dhclient command?

Comment: Please try "Fedora 36: x86_64 Live ISO" from here: https://getfedora.org/en/workstation/download/ Also I'm curious what Dell XP is. They have an XPS lineup, not "XP".

Comment: Please show the output of, `lspci | egrep -i 'network|ethernet|wireless|wi-fi'`, `ip l` and `sudo ethtool name_of_your_network_interface` (e.g. `enp2s0`).

Comment: Please edit your original question to add answers and further explanations: Is the internet connection via ethernet working for you? In that case, is that enough, or is it necessary to get wifi working too because you want to run the computer, where it is difficult or impossible to connect via a cable? Anyway, would it be possible for you to download and run the [Ubuntu Forum's `system-info` script](https://github.com/UbuntuForums/system-info/)? In that case, let it upload the result to a pastebin and put a link to it in your original question. That information will help us help you :-P

Comment: Hi, kiwirocker! It's very unlikely you're "thick"! The thing is, we just don't know *how* it failed to connect to wifi. On any laptop I owned, it literally was just clicking on the network symbol, if disabled enable wifi, and then select the network I want to use. But sometimes things are more complicated, for example if your wifi card needs *firmware* to be loaded by the driver, which the live USB stick might not contain – for logistic or for legal reasons. But this is all a bit of guess work. Can you tell us how you tried to establish a Wifi connection?

Comment: Output of terminal command `ifconfig -a` may be helpful for answering your question.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably watch a youtube video on how to connect to a Wifi / Ethernet on Linux mint, it's pretty straightforward actually:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qdhYpnkssO8

Comment: It it's straightforward, maybe just share the answer ;-)

Comment: Straightforward means that the steps are known, no need to repeat them here, watching a video would not hurt anyone, also there might be helpful comments/answers/questions from people like the person who asked.